bigquery write_truncate option doesn't work in spark bigquery connector
I'm trying to overwrite a BigQuery table using the WRITE_TRUNCATE option with the Spark BigQuery connector. I have verified that the target table is updated as the Last modified timestamp changes after the job completes, but the schema does not update. Adding or deleting columns does not reflect in the schema.
I am running PySpark with the Spark BigQuery connector (GitHub repository).
I am triggering the Dataproc serverless batch job with this batch configuration:
BATCH_CONFIG = {
    "runtime_config": {
        "version": "2.1",
    },
    "pyspark_batch": {
        "main_python_file_uri": "gs://MYBUCKET/main.py",
        "python_file_uris": ["gs://MYBUCKET/dataproc_template.zip"],
        "args": [
            "--template", "JDBCTOBIGQUERY",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.url", "URI",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.table", f"({sql}) as {table_name}",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.partitioncolumn", "PARTITION",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.lowerbound", "0",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.upperbound", "4",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.numpartitions", "4",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.output.mode", "overwrite",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.input.fetchsize", "10000",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.output.dataset", f"{BQ_DESTINATION_DATASET_NAME}",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.output.table", f"{BQ_DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME}",
            "--jdbc.bigquery.temp.bucket.name", "MYBUCKET"
        ],
        "jar_file_uris": [
            "gs://MYBUCKET/mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar",
            "gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13-0.32.2.jar"
        ]
    }
}

This is the write part of the PySpark script:
# Write
input_data.write \
    .format("bigquery") \
    .option("persistentGcsBucket", bq_temp_bucket) \
    .mode(output_mode) \
    .save(f"{big_query_dataset}.{big_query_table}")

I have verified that the schema of input_data is correct using printSchema(). I also checked the BigQuery job info, and createDisposition and writeDisposition are set correctly. However, the schema fields are incorrect and show the old version.
Here is the job information:
bq show --format=prettyjson --job=true PROJECT:US.JOB_ID
{
  "configuration": {
    "jobType": "LOAD",
    "load": {
      "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
      "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "DATASET",
        "projectId": "PROJECT_ID",
        "tableId": "TARGET_TABLE_yyyymmdd"
      },
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "col1",
            "type": "INTEGER"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "col2",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "name": "col3",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ]
      },
      "sourceFormat": "PARQUET",
      "sourceUris": [
        "gs://MYBUCKET/part-1.snappy.parquet",
        "gs://MYBUCKET/part-2.snappy.parquet",
        "gs://MYBUCKET/part-3.snappy.parquet",
        "gs://MYBUCKET/part-4.snappy.parquet"
      ],
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    }
  },
  "id": "PROJECT:US.JOBID",
  "jobCreationReason": {
    "code": "REQUESTED"
  },
  "jobReference": {
    "jobId": "JOBID",
    "location": "US",
    "projectId": "PROJECT_ID"
  },
  "kind": "bigquery#job",
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  }
}

Why isn't the schema updating correctly even though the WRITE_TRUNCATE option is set? How can I ensure the schema changes are reflected in the BigQuery table?

I resolved the issue by updating the Dataproc runtime version to 2.2.
